# Why am I not seeing my Java / SalesForce / Google App?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, wsdl, salesforce, mime-types

I'm currently working on a SalesForce.com tutorial entitled [Force.com for Google App Engine for Java: Getting Started](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Force.com_for_Google_App_Engine_Setup_Guide_Java)

I've installed the Google Eclipse Plugin, downloaded the libraries, and entered the "Hello World App" (as seen on the tutorial page):

```
package com.force;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.logging.*;

import com.sforce.ws.*;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.*;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.sobject.SObject;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldServlet.class.getName());

    private String username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private String password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private PartnerConnection connection;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world. this is a test2");

        PrintWriter t = resp.getWriter();
        getConnection( t, req);
        if ( connection == null ) { return; }

        QueryResult result = null;

        try {

            result = connection.query(  "select id, name, phone from Account order by LastModifiedDate desc limit 10 ");

        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (SObject account : result.getRecords()) {
             t.println("<li>"+ (String)account.getField("Name") + "</li>");
        }
    }

    void getConnection(PrintWriter out, HttpServletRequest req)  { 

        try { 
            // build up a ConnectorConfig from a sid
            String sessionid = req.getParameter("sid");
            String serverurl = req.getParameter("srv");

            if ( connection == null ) { 

               out.println("<p>new connection needed</p>");
               // login to the Force.com Platform
               ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
               if ( sessionid != null && serverurl != null) {
                   config.setServiceEndpoint(serverurl);
                   config.setSessionId(sessionid);
                   config.setManualLogin(false);
                   out.println("using session from query string");
               }   else { 
                   config.setUsername(username);
                   config.setPassword(password);
               }
               connection = Connector.newConnection(config);
               out.println( connection.getConfig().getSessionId() );
               out.println( connection.getConfig().getServiceEndpoint() );
           } else { 
               out.println("<p> reuse existing connection"); 
               out.println( connection.getConfig().getSessionId() );
           }
           log.warning("Connection SID " +connection.getConfig().getSessionId());

        } catch ( ConnectionException ce) {
            log.warning("ConnectionException " +ce.getMessage());

            out.println( ce.getMessage() + " s " + ce.getClass() );

        }

    }
}
```

When I run the application as a "Web Application" I get the following in the console:

```
Initializing AppEngine server
Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Successfully processed D:\education\java\HelloWorldOriginal\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Successfully processed D:\education\java\HelloWorldOriginal\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
Warning: default mime table not found: C:\devtool\Java\jre6\lib\content-types.properties
```

When I try to visit http://localhost:8080/ , I see:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8080
Did you mean: localhost-­8080.­com
Additional suggestions:
Try reloading: localhost:­8080
Search on Google:

Google Chrome Help - Why am I seeing this page?
©2011 Google - Google Home
```

But when I visit http://localhost:8888/ , I get:

```
Web Application Starter Project

Please enter your name:
    Send
```

(Which, also isn't the desired or expected outcome.)

What is this content-type.properties that I'm missing and how can I fix it?  Or is that just a symptom of a greater problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that your web.xml directs requests for `/` to the appropriate handler class? Just writing the class isn't enough - you have to make sure that incoming requests are directed to it.

Comment: I think you may be onto something with that... I vaguely remember doing that for some earlier Dynamic Web Apps, but then discovering that newer ones didn't need this because of some annotation.... I'll try this and get back to you.  :-)

Comment: Now I'm getting some other errors, but I'll sort them out later.  Cheers for fixing the one I asked about.  :-)